# Multiple traits for onQuery

Tags: actions-on-google

For example, I am trying to implement the onQuery request for air conditioning unit.
This has 3 traits involved. However, the return only loads states under device id.
Do I load all the states for different traits into the return under that device id?
Please advice. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

[A QUERY response](https://developers.google.com/assistant/smarthome/reference/intent/query) is expected to have a single map with all of the states for a particular device ID. If the device has the traits OnOff, Brightness, and ColorSetting, the response would look like:

```
{
  "requestId": "ff36a3cc-ec34-11e6-b1a0-64510650abcf",
  "payload": {
    "devices": {
      "123": {
        "on": true,
        "online": true
      },
      "456": {
        "on": true,
        "online": true,
        "brightness": 80,
        "color": {
          "name": "cerulean",
          "spectrumRGB": 31655
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```